# How to switch between the virtual consoles ttyv1, ttyv2 10 on FreeBSD?

Tags: freebsd, kde, keyboard-shortcuts, console, tty

The <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F1..F12</kbd> keybinding does not work.

I'm using kde interface.

Comment: You do not need CTRL use ALT + F1-F2-F3

Comment: ALT + F1-F2-F3 does not work

Comment: Open terminal emulator (`xterm` or similar), run `chvt 1` and report the result.

Comment: # chvt 1
chvt: Command not found.

Comment: @jimmij from the tags, it looks like he is using X11 and KDE. If I recall, you need to flip to tty7...I don't have a box in front of me to check. If nothing else, <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> should work, but it'll kill the X server and may cause all unsaved data to be lost.